# Restrict pure-ftpd specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, restrict

Currently I have a directory where FTP users are able to access, named /data. In /data, there are /data/folder1, /data/folder2, /data/folder3. My question is can I make use of pure-ftpd (in Ubuntu 14.04) to restrict such that the FTP users are only able to enter /data/folder2? I do not mind if they can view all the directories, but I need to make sure all FTP users have no privilege to enter /data/folder1 and /data/folder3. I appreciate if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

What if you change the group of the folders 1 and 3 to something different than ftpgroup and restrict permissions? (or the opposite, assign only folder 2 to ftpgroup)